Flutter Error ConcurrentModificationError (Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:0) of '_GrowableList'.)
I have this code that throws ConcurrentModificationError (Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:0) of '_GrowableList'.) error but I am modifying a copy of the map not the map itself.
I have a database that loos something like this:
Map tasks = {
"10-10-2011": [Event(title:"Hello", done: true), Event(), Event()], 
"10-05-2011": [Event(title:"Hello123", done: false), Event(), Event()], 

}

Here is my code with the error that stops at the Value
void addUnfinishedTasks() {
    Map tasksCopy = tasks;
    String today = DateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 10);
    tasksCopy.forEach((key, value) {
      if (key != today) {
        for (Event task in value) {
          if (!task.done) {
            tasks[key].remove(task);
            if (tasks.containsKey(today)) {
              tasks[today].add(task);
            } else {
              tasks[today] = [task];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
  updateDataBase();
  }`

I tried adding other copies of the maps and lists also created copy of the value, but nothing worked.

The tasks having List values, and on dart, object of an instance is passed by reference.  You can recreate the List for tasksCopy
You can replace Map tasksCopy = tasks; with
    Map<String, List<Event>> tasksCopy = Map.fromEntries(tasks.entries.map(
      (e) => MapEntry(e.key, e.value.toList()),
    ));


This solved the issue. Thank you so much!
